# Link to element`s id and centering screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, center

I have link to section like this:

```
<a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
```

How i can to center (vertically) the screen, and section to be in the middle of screen not to the top.

Thank`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think that what you want is possible without using Javascript.

If you are able to use js, you could use this code:

```
function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
element = $(selector);
offset = element.offset();
offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
}, time);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I'm visualizing correctly there is no way I believe.